# Ember: set property on resolve promise

Tags: ember.js

I just upgraded ember from 1.11.1 to 1.13.2, and ember-data to 1.13.4

Since then, I'm not able to set a property on a resolved promise:

```
var promise = store.filter('user', {filters: {"googleId":content.id}}, function() {
        return promise;
 }).then(function(response) {
      var user = response.get('content.0');

      console.log(user); //--> A user entity (Object { type: makeCtor/Class(), id: "38", store: Object, [...])

      user.set('foo', "bar"); // CRASH HERE
 }, function(){ [...] });
```

The error message from the console is no help, since I'm in a `.then()`

EDIT :
Context :
I'm inside a initializer called `session.js`. I'm trying to realise a Google authentication. This specific piece of code is just after retrieving the Google infos from the API. I'm trying to see if an user with such a google ID exists in my back-end, and if it's the case (promise resolved), I want to update the user with the up-to-date google informations and save them to my back-end (hence the `.set()`)

Comment: `return user.set('foo', "bar");` and add a `.catch(console.log.bind(console))` at the end to get the error

Comment: `TypeError: user.set is not a function` : Looks like Ember doesn't treat this as a proper model

Comment: You shouldn't be using content, `var promise = store.filter(.... return promise)` what is this code....

Comment: What should be the proper syntax?

Comment: Can you add the rest of the code that goes along with this? Where are you calling it and what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the debugger, I figured an other way to access the data that works:

```
var promise = store.filter('user', {filters: {"googleId":content.id}}, function() {
        return promise;
 }).then(function(response) {
      var user = arguments[0];

      console.log(user); //--> A user entity

      user.set('foo', "bar"); // OK NOW
 }, function(){ [...] });
```

I am really surprised, as the arguments seems to come from nowhere. There is maybe a cleaner way to do it.